# Sample example for repository unit test. Im just studing the basic so please explain it for me detail with code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

my Repository is

```
namespace Employee.Infrastructure
{
    public interface IEmployeeRepository
    {
        Employee Get(int id);
        IEnumerable<Employee> AllEmployee();
    }
    public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
    {
        public Employee Get(int id)
        {
            return AllEmployee().First(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> AllEmployee()
        {
            return new List<Employee>
            {
    
        } //......................
```

My unit test

```
private Mock<IEmployeeRepository> _employeeRepository;
private HomeController _controller;

public EmployeeRepositoryTest()
{
    _employeeRepository = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task Get_EmployeeDetails_ReturnsOk()
{
    // Arrange
    var id = 1; 
    var employee= new Employee(); 
    _employeeRepository.Setup(repo => repo.Get(id)).Returns(employee);
    _controller = new HomeController(_employeeRepository.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await _controller.GetEmployeeDetails(id);

    // Assert
    var objResult = result as ObjectResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(objResult); 
    Assert.AreEqual(employee, objResult.Value); 
}
```

My unit test: public EmployeeRepositoryTest() and this one is with red await controller.GetStaffDetails(id);
is underlined.
I would like to ask someone's help who can easy way explain to me how I did it wrong and would show me the right code. Thanks a lot

Comment: None of the code shown defines or uses `GetStaffDetails`. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77732207/edit) the question to supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).